# CyberSource REST API Recurring Payments or Installment Payments

Tags: cybersource

CyberSource has the capability of doing Recurring Payments or Installment Payments, and there is [detailed documentation](http://apps.cybersource.com/library/documentation/dev_guides/Recurring_Billing/SO_API/Recurring_Billing_SO_API.pdf) on how to do this with the Simple Order API.

However, the [REST API docs](https://developer.cybersource.com/api-reference-assets/index.html#payments) do not have an example of Recurring/Installment payments.

There is a `recurringOptions` object that has a `firstRecurringPayment` boolean.  There is also an `installmentInformation` object, but the use of these things is unclear.

How do I use the REST API to initiate a Recurring Payment or Installment Payment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately the answer is lurking in the [upgrade guide](https://developer.cybersource.com/api/upgrade-guide.html):

> Upcoming REST APIs
>
> - Fraud Management (Decision Manager)
> - Recurring Billing
> - Alternative Payments
> - PayPal
> - Tax Calculation

So the "installment" options in the REST API are misleading.  Recurring billing is not supported via this API as of October 2019.

Answer (score 1):

With the advent of REST Library, the previous Subscription Services/Recurring Billing:
(which includes

- on-demand (used with token 'vaults' and 'saving of cc for future use')
- recurring (setting a date/time for money to be 'charged', used with gyms, clubs, & monthy dues)
- installment (setting a number of payments of a specified dollar amount until paid-in-full)

These tokenization part essentially was 'removed/pieced' away as Token Management Service (TMS) the removed subscription services that provide 'recurring billing'.

As you have discovered in the [upgrade guide:](https://developer.cybersource.com/api/upgrade-guide.html) , there is plans to have a REST API library that includes subscription services or Recurring Billing that will make the former system more flexible.  In the meantime, with REST, the "services" to create and track subscriptions is left to the merchant developer to track and maintain.